# Отображение в GWT

Tags: gwt, java

Есть ли способ воспользоваться отображением на пользовательской стороне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Рефлекшны специально не были реализованы, а все тикеты с предложениями добавить такие функции - отклонены.

Comment: Печаль :(

Comment: Ну часто можно обойтись каким-то решениями на основе интерфейсов + иногда могут понадобиться какие-нибудь мапы.

Comment: Это все понятно. Надо код писать, который, в принципе, уже написан.